# EF Migration is generating a second index for the aggregate PK

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am trying to create a new migration for my project and i just depared with an awkward situation... I have my aggregate root entity:

```
public class Classroom : Entity, IAggregateRoot
{
    // PK
    public int ClassroomId { get; set; }

    // ....
    public virtual ClassroomStreaming Streaming { get; set; }
}
```

And the aggregate:

```
public class ClassroomStreaming : Entity
{
    // PK
    public int ClassroomId { get; set; }
    public virtual Classroom Classroom { get; set; }

    // Fields
    public string EmbedCode { get; set; }

    // ...
}
```

The mappings are:

```
public class ClassroomMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Classroom>
{
    public ClassroomMap()
    {
        this.HasKey(t => t.ClassroomId);
        this.ToTable("Classroom");
        // ....

        // One to One
        this.HasOptional(t => t.Streaming)
            .WithRequired(p => p.Classroom);
    }
}
```

and:

```
public class ClassroomStreamingMap: EntityTypeConfiguration<ClassroomStreaming>
{
    public ClassroomStreamingMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => new { t.ClassroomId });

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("ClassroomStreaming");

        this.Property(t => t.ClassroomId)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

        // Relationships
        this.HasRequired(t => t.Classroom)
            .WithOptional(p => p.Streaming)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
    }
}
```

When I generate the migration, i get the following situation where it creates the PK and also an non clustered index for the same column:

```
public override void Up()
{
    CreateTable(
        "dbo.ClassroomStreaming",
        c => new
            {
                ClassroomId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                // ....
            })
        .PrimaryKey(t => t.ClassroomId)
        .ForeignKey("dbo.Classroom", t => t.ClassroomId, cascadeDelete: true)
        .Index(t => t.ClassroomId);
}
```

Is it a normal behavior? look how it is in the SQL Server:

[image: Awkward]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like based you have "double-mapped" your relationships in the two `EntityTypeConfiguration<T>` classes. I think you only need to define the relationship in one direction.

The [Entity Framework Fluent API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx#RequiredToOptional) documentation states that for one-to-zero-or-one relationships, define it with `.HasOptional().WithRequired()` as you have done in the `ClassroomMap`. You should be able remove the `.HasRequired().WithOptional()` in the `ClassroomStreamingMap` class.